# dotx (Word Template) file manipulation using ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have a **dotx** file which contains placeholders to be replaced with DB values including Image place-holders.

Should I convert **dotx** file to **docx** first and then replace the placeholders in my .net application?

Or there is some other way to do same.

Please guide.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my current scenerio, 
I will be using Aspose library to do doc/docx/dotx manipulation and then finally converting the result document to pdf after mail merge. I have downloaded the free 30-days trial version and it seems to solve all my issues.

I would suggest anyone going to use Aspose to have the trial version first and then making the decision.